# Snowflake stored procedure, check if a resultset is empty without throwing an error

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

somewhat related to another snowflake question I opened [In a Snowflake stored procedures, is there a way to check how many columns are in a resultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64778610/in-a-snowflake-stored-procedures-is-there-a-way-to-check-how-many-columns-are-i)

Is there a way to check if a resultset is empty? For example

```
var query = `SELECT * FROM somewhere`
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: query});
var result = stmt.execute();
result.next()
var colCount = stmt.getColumnCount();
```

errors if there was no data returned in the resultset. It says

`Failed Code 100183 State P0000 Message ResultSet is empty or not prepared, call next() first`

I tried flipping it just to see what would happen.

```
var query = `SELECT * FROM somewhere`
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: query});
var result = stmt.execute(); 
var colCount = stmt.getColumnCount();
result.next();
```

It looks like both of these lines `var colCount = stmt.getColumnCount();` and `result.next();` throw the same error regardless of order. I suspect that the error is because result set is empty. If my suspicion is correct then I need another way to check that. Is there a safe way to check that there is any data in result at all before this error gets thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the count of a resultset this way:

> statement.getRowCount();

In your code, you would do this:

```
var query = `SELECT * FROM somewhere`
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: query});
var result = stmt.execute();
if (stmt.getRowCount() > 0) {
    result.next()
    var colCount = stmt.getColumnCount();
} else {
    // Do something here if no rows in the resultset.
}
```